# How to plot two graphs using matplotlib in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data i this file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4KXs5bh3CmPWXJkQWhkbzI0WEE

```
#count weekdays 0 to 4
mUserType = np.where(rides['starttime'].dt.dayofweek <= 5, 'Weekend', 
'Weekday')
#count hours
mWeekHours = rides['starttime'].dt.hour
#create group by usertype
WeekdayWorkdayResult = rides.groupby([mUserType, mWeekHours, 
'usertype']).size().unstack()
WeekdayWorkdayResult
```

this code count the hours of weekends and weekdays according to the usertype i.e. Customer and Subscriber

I want to plot the graph using matplotlib in this format how can I?[Weekday and Weekend Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alexy.png)

which shows the number of rides by Hour and User Type. One plot for Workdays and the second for Weekends. Include a plot line for All hourly rides

```
# count trips by date and by hour

ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(rides.starttime)
rides['date'] = ind.date.astype('datetime64')
rides['hour'] = ind.hour
by_hour = rides.pivot_table('tripduration', aggfunc='count',
                       index=['date', 'hour'],
                       columns='usertype').fillna(0).reset_index('hour')

# average these counts by weekend
by_hour['weekend'] = (by_hour.index.dayofweek >= 5)
by_hour = by_hour.groupby(['weekend', 'hour']).mean()
by_hour.index.set_levels([['weekday', 'weekend'],
                     ["{0}:00".format(i) for i in range(24)]],
                    inplace=True);
by_hour.columns.name = None
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 6), sharey=True)
by_hour.loc['weekday'].plot(title='Hourly Rides User Type and Hour', 
ax=ax[0])
by_hour.loc['weekend'].plot(title='Weekend Rides by User Type and Hour', 
ax=ax[1])
ax[0].set_ylabel('Hourly Rides by User Type');
```

Here is the code i get only subscriber and customer's data  i also want to get all graph line means sum of hours for both sub and cust for weekdend  and workdays

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subplot` for many graphs on one plot.

Tell it how many rows and columns, and which you are plotting.
There's a demo [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#set up data

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1) #two rows, one columns, first graph
#Call plt.plot(x1, y1) with the data you want
plt.title('First subplot')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2) #two rows, one columns, 2nd graph
#Call plt.plot(x2, y2) with the data you want
plt.title('Second subplot')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I want to plot graph as i showed in the picture but unable to do

Comment: Can you be more explicit in the question about what you have tried and what goes wrong? You words suggested the two plots on one graph was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it is an impartial code, but this is how i plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plot(x-axis,y-axis,data)
plt.plot(x-axis,y-axis,data)

plt.show()
```

so before , if you plot twice both the line will be in the same graph.

Comment: Can you please plot the graph by using above data because i unable to do